# If $x>y>0$ why is $\sqrt{x} > \sqrt {y}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-writing, roots, radicals

> If $x>y>0$ why is $\sqrt{x} > \sqrt {y}$?

I know this to be true, but I don't understand why because can't the square root of $x$ be negative and the square root of $y$ be positive thus disproving it?

Comment: Generally, when $\sqrt{x}$ is used without any further comment, it means the positive square root.

Comment: As for why it is true, what tools are you wanting to limit us to use?  If we can use calculus to prove it to you, then the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ which is always strictly positive for all positive real numbers directly implying the result.

Comment: If you want us to prove it more directly, suppose for contradiction that $\sqrt{y}\geq \sqrt{x}\geq 0$.  Then $0\leq \sqrt{x}\cdot \sqrt{x}\leq \sqrt{x}\cdot \sqrt{y}\leq \sqrt{y}\cdot\sqrt{y}$ implying that $x\leq y$.  This follows from the *definition* of $\leq$, namely that if $a>0$ and $b\geq c$ then $ab\geq ac$.

Answer (score 8):

Because $x-y>0$, $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}>0$ and $$x-y=(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}).$$

For $a\geq0$ by definition  $\sqrt{a}$ it's non-negative number $b$ for which $b^2=a$.

All this says that $\sqrt{a}\geq0$ by definition.

When we want to define $\sqrt{a}$ we need that $\sqrt{.}$ would be function and that by our definition we don't get a contradiction with  laws of math.

If you wish to define  $\sqrt{a}$ like non-positive $b$ for which $b^2=a$ then try to check the following law:
$$\sqrt{\sqrt{a}}=\sqrt[4]{a}.$$

We see that by new definition laws of math sometimes work and sometimes  not work.

This prevents us from exploring our world.

Thus we get the correct definition of $\sqrt{.}$ and from here we can not change anything.

Comment: But couldn't x√+y√ be smaller than 0 because the square root could be negative.

Comment: @Lmorj $\sqrt a$ is called the *principle root*. The restriction is necessary so that the function passes the vertical line test.

Comment: @Lmorj See the definition of square root. I added it.

Comment: @Micheal Rozenberg why is that a definition, couldn't b = - root a

Comment: @Lmorj You're not understanding. $\sqrt{ }$ is not a *square root*, it's a *principal square root*. It is up to the mathematician to take care and say that $b^2=a\implies b=\pm \sqrt a$, because the square root can be negative as you said.

Comment: how does this actually answer the question?

Comment: you should say that it is because the first term on the RHS must be positive

Comment: It's easier for the function to return a magnitude and the mathematician assign a value rather than the function returns **two values** from the **same symbol**

Comment: @Lmorj I added something. Read please.